# Tourist Kuwaiti visa requirements for a Bangladeshi citizen

Tags: visas, kuwait, bangladeshi-citizens

Hello i am a Bangladeshi citizen.can anyone help me with the information on tourist visa for Kuwait.my fiance lives in Kuwait and she has a PR there.i would like to go for a short visit next year.cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bangladeshi citizens are blocked from being issued any kind of visa in Kuwait (visit, tourism, work, or business).  This block has been in place for more than 6 years and it affects citizens of Pakistan, Syria, Iraq, Iran, Afghanistan and Bangladesh.

The only exception is if you hold a special passport (for example, you are active military on a military exercise, a diplomat, flight crew, etc.)

In certain cases the Office of the Minister of Interior can grant exceptions, but these are rare and require a petition in writing with supporting documents (such as a salary certificate, affidavit from an employer, etc.) and is granted on a case-by-case basis; usually determined by the profession of the applicant (in Kuwait), their criminal record, length of stay and other factors.

However, as Kuwait does not recognize engagements as a valid relationship category, your fiance would not be able to sponsor you.

---

For those nationalities that are not in the blacklist, to get a tourist visa you simply apply through your hotel; which will arrange for a short visit visa (maximum stay is 30 days, and it cannot be extended).